# Python multiprocessing closing issue

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyqt5, qthread

**File ui.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 50)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Click to put action in queue"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**File main.py**

```py
from ui import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pipe
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QThread
import sys
import os
import time

class Main_Program:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.MainWindow)
        self.MainWindow.show()
        
        
        self.create_proccess()
        self.counter = 0
        #self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        
        for i in range(0,1000):
            self.button_clicked()
        
        self.MainWindow.closeEvent = lambda event:self.closeEvent(event)
        
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
        
    def button_clicked(self):
        self.queue.put(self.counter)
        self.counter += 1
        
    def create_proccess(self):
        self.mother_pipe, self.child_pipe = Pipe()
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.emitter = Emitter(self.mother_pipe)
        self.emitter.start()
        self.process = Child_Proc(self.child_pipe, self.queue)
        self.process.start()
        self.emitter.data_emitted_signal.connect(self.data_from_proccess)
        
    def data_from_proccess(self,data):
        print(data)
        
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.process.terminate()
        self.emitter.terminate()
        event.accept()
        
class Emitter(QThread):
    data_emitted_signal = pyqtSignal(int)
    
    def __init__(self, from_process: Pipe):
        super().__init__()
        self.data_from_process = from_process

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.data_from_process.recv()
            if data["type"]=="data_emitted_signal":
                self.data_emitted_signal.emit(data["data_emitted_signal"])
                
        
class Child_Proc(Process):

    def __init__(self,to_emitter, from_mother):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = False
        self.to_emitter = to_emitter
        self.data_from_mother = from_mother
        
    def run(self):
        while True:
            q_size = self.data_from_mother.qsize()
            if q_size>0:
                data = self.data_from_mother.get()
            else:
                data = None
            #pyaudio-pydub mixing with chunk time 0.744 sec
            time.sleep(0.744)
            if data is not None:
                self.to_emitter.send({"type":"data_emitted_signal","data_emitted_signal":data})
                
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    program = Main_Program()
```

The problem with the above code is that when i decide to close the app the PyQt5 window closes but the `python main.py` command doesn't return the check back to terminal.

If I clear the `self.queue` before the `event.accept()` then there is no problem.
Why this is happen, and how can i manage the closing events of Proccesses, QThreads in those   situations?

**Edit:**

The following code works:

```py
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        qsize = self.queue.qsize()
        while(qsize!=0):
            for i in range(0,qsize):
                q_data = self.queue.get()
            qsize = self.queue.qsize()
            
        self.process.terminate()
        self.emitter.terminate()
        event.accept()
```

My question is why the up code doesn't close properly, and what is the right way to close a Process/QThread ?

Comment: The right way to do this is to have some kind of a signal that tells the thread to exit.  You shouldn't have to use `terminate`.

Comment: You should also not have blocking functions in a `closeEvent` (especially since they are not related to the main thread nor the event loop), and remember that "monkey patching" event handlers is normally discouraged as it prevents proper debugging and event management. Consider using `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)` and use a signal as Tim suggests to tell processes and threads to exit gracefully.

Comment: @TimRoberts like this: https://gist.github.com/clayrichardson/3358585 ?

Comment: The kill flag is the right idea.